# Getting my home town from the Facebook API with PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I'm a basic PHP coder and am just looking for basic ways of getting information from Facebook with PHP.

At the moment I'm trying to get my home town. Below is my code, but I cannot get it to echo the hometown of myself.

```
  $mylocation = $facebook->api('/me', 'get', array("fields"=>"user_hometown"));
  echo $mylocation['hometown'];
```

Answer (score 1):

First, try doing the action in Graph API Explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer to ensure you have the correct request and correct token.  Once you can get it to work there, then move on to trying with any of the SDKs such as the PHP one you have.

Be sure to ask for the `user_hometown` permission to see it.

Comment: When I do the below for getting my name it works fine. <br>$mylocation = $facebook->api('/me', 'get', array("fields"=>"name")); echo $mylocation['name'];<br> So how do I get my hometown with the above code

Comment: `hometown` is the field you want.  And `user_hometown` is the permission you need to request when the user is authenticating your app.

Comment: Have you spend any time playing using the Graph API Explorer tool?  You will save yourself a lot of debugging time.

Comment: Yea i played with it, I just checked in the Graph API I get my home town however when I try and do the f $mylocation = $facebook->api('/me', 'get', array("fields"=>"hometown")); 
echo $mylocation['name']; ollowing I just get blank...

Comment: Please debug your access_token here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint and see if your have user_hometown permission enabled.  Also take that token and try it in the explorer too.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you are asking for user_hometown, it should be just hometown try that out and tel us how you get on.

Comment: When I do  the below for getting my name it works fine.                           <br>$mylocation = $facebook->api('/me', 'get', array("fields"=>"name")); 
  echo $mylocation['name'];<br> So how do I get my hometown with the above code?

Comment: have you changed "fields"=>"user_hometown" to "fields"=>"hometown"?